# Why is an array variable equal to its address?

Tags: c, arrays

I am new to C programming, and there is a question that bothers me.
Let's see the following piece of code:

```
int main()
{
   int arr[3]={1,2,3};
   printf("%d\n", arr);
   printf("%d", &arr);
}
```

If I run this code, it gives the same result for both arr and &arr. But why arr=&arr?
I have seen quite a lot of answers on this topic, but none of them is clear to me. In a nutshell, people agree that an array variable holds the address of the first element of the array, e.g., arr holds the address of arr[0], say arr= 4340. Then the variable arr must be stored somewhere in the memory and &arr is the address of the memory cell that stores the value 4340. If &arr = arr then it turns out that 4340 is stored at address 4340. But the value at address 4340 is the value of the first element of the array, so it should be 1???
I am very confused at this point and would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/). It's a good explanation of the often confusing relationship between arrays and pointers in C. (Rule 1: arrays are not pointers.)

Comment: @Keith Thompson: Thanks for the reference! I will definitely look at it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your confusion here has to do with the equivalency of arrays an pointers.  Namely, arrays are not pointers but in some contexts an array *decays* into a pointer.

An array **does not** hold the address to the first element, but is a contiguous set of elements of the base type.  The address of the array itself happens to be the address of the first element.

One place where the difference between a pointer and an array is significant is with the `sizeof` operator which can tell the difference.  Assuming an `int` is 4 bytes and a pointer is 8 bytes, `sizeof(arr)` will give you 12, while `sizeof(&arr)` will give you 8.

When you pass `arr` to a function, at that point it decays into a pointer to the first element.  So printing `arr` and `&arr` will give you the same value.

That being said, you should always use `%p` to print a pointer instead of `%d`, as this can cause undefined behavior.

Comment: Really it causes undefined behavior? I thought it would just print an incorrect value on platforms where `sizeof(int) != sizeof(void*)`

Comment: @AlejandroDíaz An address may not necessarily be a number.  On DOS for example, an address is not a single number but two numbers.

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour of your program is *undefined*. You cannot use `%d` as the format specifier for an array type or the address of an array type. You could have passed `arr[0]` to get the value of the first element in that array.

Occasionally `arr` does *decay* to a pointer of type `int*`, such as when it is passed to a function. The fact that `arr` is equal to `&arr` in the context of their being a parameter to `printf` with the format specifier corrected to `%p` is also due to pointer decay.

Comment: It still happens when using the valid `%p`.

Comment: My mistake. That's due to the fact that `arr` decays to a pointer. See my amended answer and @dbush answer which is better than mine.